# Retrofit Soap call

Tags: soap, retrofit2

I am trying to do retrofit soap call.

```
Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
WebRequestCommon webRequestCommon = new WebRequestCommon();
webRequestCommon.setUserName(USER_NAME);
webRequestCommon.setPassword(PASSWORD);
LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails();
loginDetails.setWebRequestCommon(webRequestCommon);
```

WebRequestCommon.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "webRequestCommon",
    propOrder = {"company", "password", "userName"}
)
public class WebRequestCommon {
protected String company;
@XmlElement(
        required = true
)
protected String password;
@XmlElement(
        required = true
)
protected String userName;

public WebRequestCommon() {
}

public String getCompany() {
    return this.company;
}

public void setCompany(String value) {
    this.company = value;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String value) {
    this.password = value;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String value) {
    this.userName = value;
}
}
```

LoginDetails.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlType(
    name = "LoginDetails",
    propOrder = {"webRequestCommon", "tciblogindetails"}
)
public class LoginDetails {
@XmlElement(
        name = "WebRequestCommon"
)
protected WebRequestCommon webRequestCommon;
@XmlElement(
        name = "TCIBLOGINDETAILS"
)
protected EnquiryInput tciblogindetails;

public LoginDetails() {
}

public WebRequestCommon getWebRequestCommon() {
    return this.webRequestCommon;
}

public void setWebRequestCommon(WebRequestCommon value) {
    this.webRequestCommon = value;
}

public EnquiryInput getTCIBLOGINDETAILS() {
    return this.tciblogindetails;
}

public void setTCIBLOGINDETAILS(EnquiryInput value) {
    this.tciblogindetails = value;
}
}
```

But while calling the service I am getting the following error

```
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
 <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: 
 unexpected XML tag. expected: 
 {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: 
 {null}loginDetails</faultstring>
  </S:Fault>
 </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

My Service API is

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
})
@POST("/TCIBCommonWS/services")
Call<LoginDetailsResponse> retrieveAccounts(@Body LoginDetails body);
```

How to specify the base url for the retrofit soap call?

What is simpleXMlConvertorFactory here. What is the use?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There's [some similar errors here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Couldn%27t%20create%20SOAP%20message%20due%20to%20exception%20unexpected%20XML%20tag).